# Kluent Pattern for matching item from list of objects

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, assertion

I have a list of objects that I'm trying to assert that one of them matches a name with kluent.

```
class User {
  String name
  int age
}

var listOfUser = listOf(User("Frank", 12), User("John", 25))
```

How can I assert that the list has a user in it with a name equal to frank, without caring what the position is?

Something in the vein of `listOfUser.shouldContain{ name=="Frank" }`.
I'm specifically trying to avoid `listofUser[0].name == "Frank"`

Comment: which library do you prefer for unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what I was looking for: `listOfUser.shouldContainAny{ it.name=="Frank" }`